# Accessing Kudan events, variables though another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, kudan

Following Kudan's SampleApp script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace Kudan.AR.Samples
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Script used in the Kudan Samples. Provides functions that switch between different tracking methods and start abitrary tracking.
    /// </summary>
    public class SampleApp : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public KudanTracker _kudanTracker;  // The tracker to be referenced in the inspector. This is the Kudan Camera object.
        public TrackingMethodMarker _markerTracking;    // The reference to the marker tracking method that lets the tracker know which method it is using
        public TrackingMethodMarkerless _markerlessTracking;    // The reference to the markerless tracking method that lets the tracker know which method it is using

        public void MarkerClicked()
        {
            _kudanTracker.ChangeTrackingMethod(_markerTracking);    // Change the current tracking method to marker tracking
        }

        public void MarkerlessClicked()
        {
            _kudanTracker.ChangeTrackingMethod(_markerlessTracking);    // Change the current tracking method to markerless tracking
        }

        public void StartClicked()
        {
            // from the floor placer.
            Vector3 floorPosition;          // The current position in 3D space of the floor
            Quaternion floorOrientation;    // The current orientation of the floor in 3D space, relative to the device

            _kudanTracker.FloorPlaceGetPose(out floorPosition, out floorOrientation);   // Gets the position and orientation of the floor and assigns the referenced Vector3 and Quaternion those values
            _kudanTracker.ArbiTrackStart(floorPosition, floorOrientation);              // Starts markerless tracking based upon the given floor position and orientations
        }
    }
}
```

To access Kudan's functions/events/variables I need to create a script using the same namespace of Kudan. I don't know what upside or downside this could have as I don't understand namespaces that much.

My question is, can I access those variables/functions/etc without making my script in the same namespace? If so, how?

I've learn programming on my own so my apologies if this seems too basic for some, and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the same namespace throughout the script, you'll need to explicitly state the namespace when you declare the variable.

So, instead of saying:

```
namespace Kudan.AR.Samples
{
    public class SampleApp
    {
        public KudanTracker _kudanTracker; 
    }
}
```

you would say:

```
public class SampleApp
{
    public Kudan.AR.KudanTracker _kudanTracker;
}
```

For more info, I would suggest looking up [how to use Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!